# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli can you help me

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Daowat\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
>   in C:\xampp\htdocs\Daowat\index.php on line 20
>
> **
>       Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\Daowat\index.php:20 Stack trace: #0
>   {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Daowat\index.php on line 20
>       **

```
     $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","daowat_db") or die("Couldn't connet to SQL server");


    <?php include ( "./inc/connect.inc.php" ); ?>
<?php 
session_start();
if (isset($_COOKIE['user_login'])) {
    $_SESSION['user_login'] = $_COOKIE['user_login'];
    header("location: index.php");
    exit();
}

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        if (isset($_POST['user_login']) && isset($_POST['password_login'])) {
            $user_login = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['user_login']);
            $user_login = mb_convert_case($user_login, MB_CASE_LOWER, "UTF-8"); 
            $password_login = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password_login']);
            $rememberme = $_POST['rememberme'];     
            $num = 0;
            $password_login_md5 = md5($password_login);
            $resulta = ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE (username='$user_login' || email='$user_login') AND password='$password_login_md5' AND activated='1' AND blocked_user='0'");
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$resulta);
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($result); //******** Line 20
            $get_user_email = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
                $get_user_uname_db = $get_user_email['username'];
            if ($num>0) {
                $_SESSION['user_login'] = $get_user_uname_db;
                if ($rememberme != NULL) {
                    setcookie('user_login', $user_login, time() + (365 * 24 * 60 * 60), "/");
                }
                header('location: index.php');
                exit();
            }
            else {
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using, the `mysql_*` library has been removed from PHPv7. Also the error is about `mysql_query` while your code uses `mysqli_query`, are you sure the error is from this part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

This error caused when  Mysql extension is not enabled in PHP configuration.

in php.ini configuration file

```
;extension=mysqli.so
```

should be

```
extension=mysqli.so
```